# CondingBat Python puzzle results in "Timed out"

Tags: python

I am trying to solve this CodingBat problem:

> We want make a package of goal kilos of chocolate. We have small bars (1 kilo each) and big bars (5 kilos each). Return the number of small bars to use, assuming we always use big bars before small bars. Return -1 if it can't be done.

I understand the logic of the problem but whenever I try to run it, I get a Timed Out exception. So can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```
def make_chocolate(small, big, goal):

  total = 0

  if goal < 5:
    big = 0
  for i in xrange(big):
    total += 5
    if total == goal:
      return 0
    elif total+5>goal:
      break
  for k in xrange(small):
    total +=1
    if total == goal:
      return (k+1)

  return -1
```

Comment: What happens if goal > small and not a multiple of 5?

Comment: Will you post the exact error?

Comment: "Timed Out" This is on codingbat, so it doesn't say much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The failure is caused by time it takes to do this test:

```
makeChocolate(1000, 1000000, 5000006)
```

Even though the other tests can pass, once one test times out, the report shows all tests as timing out.  To see this is true, change `xrange(big)` to `xrange(big if big < 101 else 0)` and you will see every test pass except for the one above.

Web based evaluators need timeouts like these for performance reasons . It must be that the  Python timeout allows for less loops than the Java timeout.

Here is non looping solution that passes:

```
def make_chocolate(small, big, goal):
    big *= 5
    if big + small < goal or small < goal%5:
        return -1
    small = goal - big
    return small%5 if small < 0 else small
```

A slightly different solution is needed for Java due to how it treats the modulo for negative numbers.

```
public int makeChocolate(int small, int big, int goal) {
    big *= 5;
    if (big + small < goal || small < goal%5)
        return -1;
    small = goal - big;
    return small < 0 ? (big+small)%5 : small;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is clunky, but it works:

```
def make_chocolate(small, big, goal):
    bigbars=goal//5
    if bigbars<=big:
        smallgoal=goal-(bigbars*5)
        if smallgoal>=0 and smallgoal<=small:
            return smallgoal
        if smallgoal>small:
            return -1
    if bigbars>big:
        smallgoal=goal-(big*5)
        if smallgoal<=small:
            return smallgoal
        if smallgoal>small:
            return -1
```

Answer (score 0):

You could simply do it this way:

```
def make_chocolate(small, big, goal):
    noOfBigs = big if(5 * big <= goal) else goal / 5
    return  goal - (noOfBigs * 5)  if small >= (goal - (noOfBigs * 5)) else -1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def make_chocolate(small, big, goal):  
    big = big*5  
    if (goal >= big) and (small >= goal - big):  
        return goal - big  
    if (goal < big) and (small >= goal % 5):  
        return goal % 5  
    return -1
```

Comment: please explain this code - give it a bit more detail as to what you are doing, and what you have done to 'fix/help' the OP

Answer (score 0):

Seems like cleaner logic if you first reduce Big value to the number you'll actually use:

```
def make_chocolate(small, big, goal):
  while big * 5 > goal:
    big -= 1
  if (goal - (big * 5)) <= small:
    return goal - (big * 5)
  else:
    return -1
```

Answer (score 0):

The below code works perfectly for all test data.
Sorry,Since it is self explanatory I didn't provide any explanation.

```
def make_chocolate(small, big, goal):
    s = small*1
    b = big*5
    mod = goal%5
    if b < goal:
        if s+b == goal:
            return s
        elif s+b > goal:
            return goal-b
        elif s+b < goal:
            return -1
    elif b > goal:
        if s < mod:
            return -1
        return mod
    elif b == goal:
        return 0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  def make_chocolate(small, big, goal):
  s_cnt = 0;
  t = goal;
  for i in range(**550**):
    if(goal >= 5 and big > 0):
        goal = goal-5;
        big = big-1;
    elif(goal > 0 and small > 0):
        goal = goal-1;
        small = small-1;
        s_cnt = s_cnt+1;

  if (goal == 0):
    return s_cnt;
  else:
    return -1;
```

// in block letters range(550) 
you can see I have hardcoded it 
because for big values it will run the loop for too long because of which
you are getting timeout error.

Answer (score 0):

```
def make_chocolate(small, big, goal):
  i = goal // 5
  b_big = big*5
  x = i*5
  y = goal - x

  if big == 0:
    if small >= goal:
      return small - (goal - small)
    else:
      return -1
  elif b_big == goal:
    return 0
  elif big >= i:
    if x + small < goal:
      return -1 
    else:
      return (goal - (x))
  else:
    if b_big + small < goal:
      return -1
    else:
      return(goal - b_big)
```

Comment: Usually it's better to explain a solution instead of just posting some rows of anonymous code. You can read [How do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), and also [Explaining entirely code-based answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bcode-based-answers)

Answer (score 0):

```
def make_chocolate(small,big,goal):
    if goal > small + big * 5:
        return -1
    else:
        if goal % 5 <= small:
            if big * 5 <=goal:
                return goal - (big * 5)
            else:
                return goal % 5
        else:
            return -1
```

Comment: Can you add any supporting explanation for this answer? How does this solve the OP's question? There are several other answers, so please tell us what makes this one work.

Answer (score 0):

```
def make_chocolate(small, big, goal):
    if goal - 5 * big == 0:
        return 0
    elif (goal - 5 * big) < 0:
        return -1 if (goal % 5) > small else goal % 5
    elif (goal - 5 * big) > small:
        return -1
    else:
        return (goal - 5 * big)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Code dumps without any explanation are rarely helpful. Stack Overflow is about learning, not providing snippets to blindly copy and paste. Please [edit] your question and explain how it works better than what the OP provided. See [answer].

Answer (score 0):

```
def make_chocolate(small, big, goal):
    can_do = small + 5*big
    if can_do<goal:
        return -1
    elif can_do==goal:
        return small
    else:
        b_max = goal/5
        b_max = b_max if b_max<=big else big
        s_req = goal - (b_max)*5
        if s_req <= small:
            return s_req
        else:
            return -1
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. It's usually a good idea to explain your code when answering a question so that others can follow your reasoning and the original poster can understand. The question was asked was "what am I doing wrong"

Answer (score 0):

```
def make_chocolate(small, big, goal):
  if(goal>=big*5) and(small+big*5>=goal) and (goal%5 <=small):
     rem_cho=abs(goal-big*5)
     return(rem_cho)
  elif(goal%5>small):
     return(-1)
  elif(goal<big*5):
     return(goal%5)
  else:
     return(-1)
```

Comment: please add some explanation

Answer (score 0):

you can try this, I tried to make it as  short as possible:

```
def make_chocolate(small, big, goal):
  if small>=goal-5*min(goal//5,big):
    return goal-5*min(goal//5,big) #this is the no of short bricks which are used.
  else:
    return -1
```

#a variable can be assigned for the no of small bricks used but i didn't want to.

Answer (score -1):

```
def make_chocolate(small, big, goal):        
  while big*5>goal:
    if goal%5==0:
      return 0
    else:
      if goal%5<=small:
        return goal%5
      else:
        return -1
    else:
      if goal-(big*5)<=small:
        return goal-(big*5)
      else:
        return -1
```

Answer (score -1):

```
def permutations(amount, size, threshold):


if amount == 1:
      return size
  combinations = []
  for i in range(1, amount + 1):
    combinations.append(size * i)
  if combinations[-1] == threshold:
      return combinations[-1]
  elif combinations[-1] > threshold:
      if size == 1:
        return combinations[-1] - threshold
      elif size == 5:
        return combinations[-2]
  else:
      return combinations

def make_chocolate(small_amount, big_amount, goal):
    "Adjusts values for small and big chocolate bars until we find out whether there is a solution"
    if big_amount == 0 and small_amount == goal:
        return goal
    elif big_amount == 0 and small_amount != goal:
        return -1
    else:
        big_size = 5
        small_size = 1
        big_sums_list = permutations(big_amount, big_size, goal)
        big_sum = big_sums_list
        if type(big_sum) == list: #If none of the sums reached our goal
            new_threshold_value = goal - big_sums_list[-1] # We adjust the new threshold value for the permutations function
            small_sums_list = permutations(small_amount, small_size, goal) #Get all possible sums with our given small values
            small_sum = small_sums_list # If the sum of our small values has indeed equaled or exceeded our goal
            if type(small_sums_list) == list:  # If the sum of our small values has not equaled nor exceeded our goal
                small_sums_list = permutations(small_amount, small_size, new_threshold_value)
                small_sum = small_sums_list
                if type(small_sums_list) == list: # If the sum of small bars has not exceeded the threshold value
                    return -1
                elif small_sum == new_threshold_value:
                    return small_sum # Whichever value we choose will be correct
                elif small_sum > new_threshold_value:
                    return new_threshold_value # It is the number of small bars we have left before our goal that matters
            elif small_sum == goal:
                return small_sum # If the sum has equaled our goal, it is indiferent whether we choose one or the other variable
            elif small_sum > goal: # If the sum has exceeded our goal
                return goal #Since the size is one, we can return goal as the result
        elif big_sum >= goal:
            return make_chocolate(small_amount, big_amount - 1, goal) # We adjust the amounts by - 1, to check for different combinations
        elif big_sum == 5:
            new_threshold_value = goal - big_sum # We adjust the new threshold value for the permutations function
            small_sums_list = permutations(small_amount, small_size, new_threshold_value) #Get all possible sums with our given small values
            small_sum = small_sums_list # If the sum of our small values has indeed equaled or exceeded our goal
            if type(small_sum) == list:  # If the sum of our small values has not equaled nor exceeded our goal
                return -1
            elif small_sum == new_threshold_value:
                return small_sum # If the sum has equaled our goal, it is indiferent whether we choose one or the other variable
            elif small_sum > new_threshold_value: # If the sum has exceeded our goal
                return goal #Since the size is one, we can return goal as the result

print(make_chocolate(4, 1, 10))
```