# Simple 'Make chocolate' logic and solution review

Tags: java, loops

I am working on a coding Bat question http://codingbat.com/prob/p191363 which has already many solutions here [CondingBat Python puzzle results in "Timed out"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15617869/condingbat-python-puzzle-results-in-timed-out).

**My solution is marked as partially right. Trying to understand the problem.**

> We want make a package of goal kilos of chocolate. We have small bars 
>   (1 kilo each) and big bars (5 kilos each). Return the number of small 
>   bars to use, assuming we always use big bars before small bars. Return
>   -1 if it can't be done.
>
> makeChocolate(4, 1, 9) → 4 makeChocolate(4, 1, 10) → -1
>   makeChocolate(4, 1, 7) → 2

From what I understand, make chocolates method should use all available big bars to reach goal and then use small bars. Am returning 0 if big bars are already enough. *Can somebody please tell me If am understanding the problem incorrectly ?*

**Here is my solution** :

```
public int makeChocolate(int small, int big, int goal) {
    if (small + big*5 < goal)  return -1;

    int smallNeeded = goal - big * 5;

    if(smallNeeded <= 0) return 0;

    return smallNeeded;
}
```

Comment: The logic you've got here in the code snippet seems to be pretty close to me. What are you having trouble with?

Comment: The code challenge does not mark my answer as correct. so I thought am understanding the problem wrong. even http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15617869/condingbat-python-puzzle-results-in-timed-out has different solutions @j.seashell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My understanding is something like this:

If not enough with big and small combined return `-1`:

```
if((small + big * 5) < goal)  
{
    return -1;
}
```

If big are more than enough reduce the `goal` by however many values of 5 (for big bars) then return the left over amount for how many small bars:

```
else if((big * 5) > goal)
{
    return goal % 5;
}
```

If there is not enough big bars to make up the `goal` reduce the value by all kilos taken up by big bars and take the remaining in small:

```
else
{
    return goal - big * 5; 
}
```

Comment: I think this fails if you don't have enough small but more than enough big.
E.g. have a goal of 12 and 3 big and 1 small:
small+big*5 = 16, which is > goal.
However, big*5 = 15 > 12 => return 12%5, which would be 2... but we have only one ruby!
We need 
if((small + big * 5) < goal || small < goal%5)  
{
    return -1;
}

Answer (score 1):

PYTHON:
Tried with a loop, did't pass on other tests.

```
def make_chocolate(small, big, goal):
        if goal <= small:
          res = small
        elif big > 0:
            for i in range(big, 0, -1):
                if goal - (5*i) <= small and goal - (5*i) >=0:
                    res = goal - (5*i)
                    break
                else:              
                  res = -1
        else:
            res = -1
   
     return res
```

Answer (score 1):

My Python solution. Make it simple when simplifying it in your mind. It took 5 minutes to solve.

```
def make_chocolate(small, big, goal):
  if(small + (big*5) < goal) or (goal % 5 > small):
    return -1
    
  if(big*5 < goal):
    return (goal - (big*5))
    
  # If big bars are larger than the goal and have enough small bars
  return goal % 5
```

Comment: Loved this solution!

Answer (score 0):

Here is my verbose solution.
I start with each test case(enough chocolates, too many chocolates, not enough smalls, not enough big) and for each test case, change the numbers to handle all possible scenarios.

```
public int makeChocolate(int small, int big, int goal) {
int result = goal % 5;  

// means we need more little pieces
if(result > 0){
    if((small + big*5) >= goal){
        if(goal-big*5 < 0){
            if((goal % 5) > small){
                return -1;
            }
            else{
                return goal % 5;
            }
        }else{
            return goal-big*5;
        }

    }else{
        return -1;
    }
} 
else{
    if(big*5 + small < goal){
        return -1;
    }
    if((goal - big*5) <= 0){
        return 0;
    }else{
        return goal - big*5;
    }   
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Unlike makeBrics one is a bit harder. Hope this would help:

```
public int makeChocolate(int small, int big, int goal) {

int bigCapacity = goal/5;

if (bigCapacity>=big && goal-big*5<=small) 
 return goal-big*5;  
else if (bigCapacity<big && goal%5<=small)
 return goal%5;

else return -1;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int needed_small = goal - Math.min((int) Math.floor(goal / 5), big) * 5;
return needed_small <= small ? needed_small : -1;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def make_chocolate(small, big, goal):
  if (goal>(small+big*5))or((goal%5)>small):
    return -1
  elif big*5>goal:
    return goal%5 
  else:
    return goal-big*5
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my approach:

```
public int makeChocolate(int small, int big, int goal) {

  if (goal % 5 <= small && goal / 5 <= big){
   return goal % 5;
  }
  else if (goal / 5 > big && small >= (goal - big * 5)){
   return goal- big * 5;
  }
  else {
   return -1;
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution:

```
def make_chocolate(small, big, goal):
  big_needed = goal // 5
  small_needed = goal % 5

  if ((small + (big * 5)) < goal) or ((big > big_needed) and (small_needed > small)):
    return -1
  elif (big < big_needed) and (small >= (small_needed + ((big_needed-big)*5))):
    return small_needed + ((big_needed-big)*5)
  else:
    return small_needed
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public int makeChocolate(int small, int big, int goal) {
  if(big*5+small<goal){
    return -1;
  }
  int hmbigMax = goal/5;
  if(hmbigMax>=big){
    if(small>=(goal-big*5)){
      return goal-big*5;
    }
    else{
      return -1;
    }
  }
  else {
    if(small>=(goal-hmbigMax*5)){
      return goal-hmbigMax*5;
    }
    else{
      return -1;
    }
  }
}
```

its true, ive got a star for this solution.

Answer (score 0):

def make_chocolate(small, big, goal):

```
  def b_req(big, goal):
    req = goal//5
    if req <= big and req > 0:
      return req
    else:
      return big


  if goal >= 5:
   s_req = goal - (b_req(big,goal)*5)
  else:
   s_req = goal

  if s_req <= small or s_req == 0:
    return s_req
  else:
    return -1
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my approach:

```
def make_chocolate(small, big, goal):

    while goal >= 5:
        if big == 0:
            break
        goal = goal - 1
        big = big - 1

    if goal > small:
        return(-1)
    else:
        return(goal)
```

Comment: While this code may provide a solution to OP's problem, it is highly recommended that you provide additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question. Code only answers typically become useless in the long-run because future viewers experiencing similar problems cannot understand the reasoning behind the solution.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me without a loop, got a star for it.

the first if statement is there to check whether it can be done(the solution for makeBricks)
once that's checked, it just checks if it can be done with only big bigs, and if so, returns 0,
then it checks if you can use all the big bars, and if so, uses them and gives the number of small bars still needed
then the next part takes the goal value, divides it by 5 to see how many big bars can be taken out, cause we now know there are enough, then multiplies that by 5 to actually get the correct amount subtracted from goal.

```
public int makeChocolate(int small, int big, int goal) {
  if ((goal%5)<=small && (goal-(big*5))<=small) {
    if (goal%5==0 && goal/5<=big)
      return 0;
    if (goal-big*5>0)
      return (goal-big*5);
    return (goal-((goal/5)*5));
  }
  return -1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def make_chocolate(small, big, goal):
  if goal<=big*5+small:
    if goal%5>small:
      return -1
    elif big*5>goal:
      return (goal%5)
    else:
      return goal-(big*5)
  else:
    return -1
```

This is my solution in python.Apologies for any mistake,this is my first post on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

```
public int makeChocolate(int small, int big, int goal) {
  while( big >0 && (big*5) > goal )
    big--;
  int remain = goal - (big *5);
  if(small - remain >= 0)
    return remain ;
 
  return -1;
}
```

Comment: How is this better than the selected answer?

Answer (score 0):

```
def make_chocolate(small, big, goal):
    if small + big*5<goal:
        return -1
    elif goal%5<=small and big*5<=goal:
        return goal - (big*5)
    elif goal%5<=small and big*5>goal:
        return (goal - abs(goal/5)*5)
    else:
        return -1
```

Here is a simple example showing how this code works;

```
def make_chocolate(4,4,18)
    if 4 + 4*5 < 18:
            return -1  (which is not the case)

    elif 18%5<=4 and 4*5<=18:
            return 18 - (4*5)  (this is also not the case)

    elif 18%5<=4 and 4*5>18:
            return (18 - abs(18/5)*5)

    else:
            return -1
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Answer (score 0):

Below is my answer in python in working condition

```
def make_chocolate(small, big, goal):
    rem = goal // 5
    if big >= rem:  #if big count is greater than reminder
       req_small = goal - 5 * rem
       res = small - req_small  #gives you remaining small
       if res < 0:  #this is for negative
          return res
       if res >= 0:
          used = small - res  #subtracting  require small from small count
          return used

    elif big < rem:  # if big count is less than reminder
         req_small = goal - 5 * big
         res = small - req_small  #gives you how many small count remain
         if res < 0:  #this is for negative 
            return res
         if res >= 0:
            used = small - res  #subtracting  req small from small count
            return used
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's mine. It incorporates the solution to makeBricks, but requires a preceding if
statement to catch the instances of needing lots of smalls to cover what the bigs can not.

```cs
public int makeChocolate(int small, int big, int goal) {
    if (big * 5 <= goal && goal - big * 5 <= small) {
        return goal - (big * 5);
    } else if (goal <= small + big * 5 && goal % 5 <= small) {
        return goal % 5;
    }
    return - 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def make_chocolate(small, big, goal):
return [-1, goal - min(goal // 5, big) * 5][goal % 5 <= small and goal <= big * 5 + small]
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Would you mind explaining why your code solves the problem? This is not a forum for everyone to show their best solutions. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
def make_chocolate(small, big, goal):
  if 5 * big + small < goal:
    return -1
  if goal % 5 == 0 and goal - 5 * big <= 0:
    return 0
  if goal - 5 * big >= 0:
    return (goal - 5 * big)
  if goal - 5 * big < 0 and goal % 5 <= small:
    return goal % 5
  else:
    return -1
```

Comment: Please explain your solution. Answers which do not have an explanation and are only code get flagged as low effort.

Answer (score 0):

Solution without loop

```
def make_chocolate(small, big, goal):
  needed = goal - big*5
  if goal > big*5+small:
    return -1
  if needed>=0:
    return needed
  if needed<=0 and goal%5 <= small:
    return goal%5
  else:
    return -1
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my answer.

```
public int makeChocolate(int small, int big, int goal) {
    int totalBig = 5*big; // determind the total amount of big in KG.

    if (totalBig>goal) { // if total big KG is more then what goal needs
        big = goal/5; // change the big to whatever it needs but not more then goal.
        totalBig = 5*big; // now the total big KG needed is not more then goal.
    }

    int smallNeeded = goal-totalBig; // you should get the rest from here on

    if (smallNeeded>small) {
        return -1; 
    }
    return smallNeeded;
}
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution:

```
public int makeChocolate(int small, int big, int goal) {
  int remainder;
  if (goal > (big * 5 + small)) {
    return -1;
  }
  
  if (goal >= big * 5) {
    remainder = goal -  (big * 5);
  } else {
    remainder = goal % 5;
  }
  
  if (remainder > small) {
    return -1;
  }
  
  return remainder;
 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def make_chocolate(small, big, goal):
  bigneed=0
  smallneed = 0

  if (5*big) >= goal:
    bigneed =  goal/ 5 
    smallneed =  goal - 5*bigneed

  if (5*big) < goal:
    bigneed = big
    smallneed = goal - 5*bigneed

  if smallneed > small :
    return -1
  else:
    return smallneed
```

Comment: Hey thanks for contributing to stack overflow! You can improve your answer with an explanation of how it works/why it’s correct. Answers with more explanation tend to get upvoted more and are more useful.

Answer (score 0):

My optimized solution

```
    public int makeChocolate(int small,int big, int goal){
      if((goal <= big*5 + small) && (goal%5 <=small)){
        int rem = goal/5;
        return rem>=big ? goal-big*5 : goal-rem*5;
      }
      return -1;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    public int makeChocolate(int small, int big, int goal) {
       boolean checkBig = goal / 5 >= big;
       int residue;
       if (checkBig) {
           residue = goal - big * 5;
       } else {
           residue = goal - (goal / 5 * 5);
       }
       return small >= residue ? residue : -1;
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

My slim approach (Maybe should have put it in a variable):

```
def make_chocolate(small, big, goal):

    return(max(0, goal//5 -big)*5+goal%5 if small >= max(0, goal//5 -big)*5+goal%5 else -1)
```

Max( 0 , goal//5 - big) compares amount of needed big with how many big available, and change a negative result with 0. The result * 5 + goal%5 takes missing big * 5 and adds the reminder and compares it with available small.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

This is my approach:

```
def make_chocolate(small, big, goal):
  nec = 5
  for x in range(big):
    if goal >= nec:
      goal = goal - nec
    else:
      break
  if goal <= small:
    return goal
  else:
    return -1
```